# iOS Charts(Daniel Gindi) - Two LineChartDataSet with different color failed

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I am trying to build a graph with 2 `LineChartDataSet`. At the first time, I build with one and then on every selected value, I want to do some different color to the right data set yet it seems like the last set sort of run over the settings and do it the opposite:

```
 class GraphTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var yieldLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var yieldPercentLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lineChart: LineChartView!
    @IBOutlet weak var graphButtonView: AssetGraphButtonView!
    @IBOutlet weak var endDateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startDateLabel: UILabel!
    
    var selectionView: AssetGraphSelectionView!

    var viewModel: GraphViewModelType!
    var set: LineChartDataSet!
    var set1: LineChartDataSet!
    var marker = BalloonMarker(color: .red,
                               font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15),
                               textColor: .white,
                               insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 10, right: 3))
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
    
    func config(with viewModel: GraphViewModelType) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        yieldLabel.attributedText = viewModel.titleAttributeText
        yieldPercentLabel.attributedText = viewModel.yielAttributeText
        startDateLabel.attributedText = viewModel.startDateAttributeText
        endDateLabel.attributedText = viewModel.endDateAttributeText

        graphButtonView.confgiureCell(with: self.viewModel.btnData)
        setUpChart()
    }
    
    func setUpChart() {
        lineChart.delegate = self
        lineChart.noDataText = "No Data Available"
        lineChart.rightAxis.enabled = false
        lineChart.leftAxis.enabled = false
        lineChart.xAxis.enabled = false
        lineChart.legend.enabled = false
        lineChart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        lineChart.drawMarkers = true
        lineChart.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
        lineChart.pinchZoomEnabled = false
        lineChart.scaleXEnabled = false
        lineChart.scaleYEnabled = false
        

        marker.chartView = lineChart
        marker.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 28, height: 20)
        lineChart.marker = marker
        
        
        let dataSets = viewModel.getLineChartDataSet()
        let data = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
        data.setValueFont(.systemFont(ofSize: 7, weight: .light))
        lineChart.data = data
    }
    
    extension GraphTableViewCell: ChartViewDelegate {
    func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
        
        let transform = lineChart.getTransformer(forAxis: .left)
        
        let point = transform.pixelForValues(x: highlight.x, y: highlight.y)

        print("point : x = \(point.x) y = \(point.y)")

        let color = self.lineChart.colorOfPoint(point: point)
        marker.color = color
        
        let dataSets = viewModel.chartValueSelected(entry: entry)
        lineChart.data = dataSets
    }
   }
```

This is the viewModel:

```
final class GraphTableViewCellViewModel: GraphViewModelType {
    var startDateAttributeText = NSMutableAttributedString()
    var endDateAttributeText =  NSMutableAttributedString()
    
    var titleAttributeText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Orion-Bold", size: 14)!, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black])
    
    var yielAttributeText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(String(format: "%.2f%%", abs(14)))", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Orion-Bold", size: 14)!, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.green])
    
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    var btnData: [AssetGraphButtonViewViewModel]
    
    var data: TwrGraph
    var dataSet = [LineChartDataSet]()
    
    var set: LineChartDataSet!

    var set1: LineChartDataSet!

    init(with data: TwrGraph) {
        btnData = AssetGraphViewModel(security: nil).assetGraphData
        self.data = data
        
        startDateAttributeText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: data.startDate, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Orion-Regular", size: 12)!, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : ColorName.warmGreyTwo])
        endDateAttributeText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: data.endDate, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Orion-Regular", size: 12)!, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : ColorName.warmGreyTwo])
        
    }
    
    func getChartDataPoints(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) -> [ChartDataEntry] {
        var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
        
        for count in (0..<dataPoints.count) {
            dataEntries.append(ChartDataEntry.init(x: Double(count), y: values[count]))
        }
        return dataEntries
    }
    
    func getLineChartDataSet() -> [LineChartDataSet] {
        let dataWeeklyDate = self.data.weeklyGraph.map { $0.date }
        let dataWeeklyYield = self.data.weeklyGraph.map { $0.yield }
        
        let dataPoints = getChartDataPoints(dataPoints: dataWeeklyDate, values: dataWeeklyYield)
        
        set = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataPoints, label:"")

        setup(set)
        return [set]
    }
    
    func setup(_ dataSet: LineChartDataSet) {
        
        dataSet.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = false
        dataSet.drawVerticalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true
        
        dataSet.isDrawLineWithGradientEnabled = true
        dataSet.fillAlpha = 0.15
        dataSet.lineWidth = 2
        dataSet.circleRadius = 0
        dataSet.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false
        dataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
        dataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
        dataSet.highlightColor = .blue
        
        let rightColor = [ChartColorTemplates.colorFromString("#FA3A7A"), ChartColorTemplates.colorFromString("#C257B1"),
                          ChartColorTemplates.colorFromString("#8B73E8")]
        
        dataSet.colors = rightColor
        
        dataSet.gradientPositions = [0, 40, 100]
        
        let gradientColors = [ChartColorTemplates.colorFromString("#FC4684").cgColor,
                              ChartColorTemplates.colorFromString("#D8D8D8").cgColor]
        let colorLocations:[CGFloat] = [1.0, 0.0]
        if let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: gradientColors as CFArray, locations: colorLocations) {
            dataSet.fill = LinearGradientFill(gradient: gradient, angle: 90.0)
        }
        
        dataSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
    }
    
    func updateSetAfterTouch(_ dataSet: LineChartDataSet) {
        
        dataSet.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = false
        dataSet.drawVerticalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true
        
//        dataSet.isDrawLineWithGradientEnabled = true
        dataSet.fillAlpha = 0.15
        dataSet.lineWidth = 2
        dataSet.circleRadius = 0
        dataSet.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false
        dataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
        dataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
//        dataSet.highlightColor = .blue
        
        
        dataSet.colors = [.red]
    }
    
    func chartValueSelected(entry: ChartDataEntry) -> LineChartData {
        return updateSet(with: entry)
    }
    
    func updateSet(with entry: ChartDataEntry) -> LineChartData {

        
        var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
        var dataEntries1: [ChartDataEntry] = []
       
        for count in (0..<self.data.weeklyGraph.count) {
            if count < self.data.weeklyGraph.count && count < Int(entry.x) {
                dataEntries.append(ChartDataEntry.init(x: Double(count), y: self.data.weeklyGraph[count].yield))
            } else {
                dataEntries1.append(ChartDataEntry.init(x: Double(count), y: self.data.weeklyGraph[count].yield))
            }
        }
        
        set = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label:"")
        set1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries1, label:"")

        setup(set)
        updateSetAfterTouch(set1)
        
        let data = LineChartData(dataSets: [set1, set])
        return data
    }
}
```

As you can see when value is selected and I am using it to create two `ChartDataEntry` and the two `LineChartDataSet` that one continue the other (in the x axis ). This is the image when we first entering(looks fine):

[image]

This is the image when selecting:

[image]

Comment: Could u fix this?

Comment: @udi Give me a couple of hours :)
Rough week

Answer (score 0):

After creating two `LineChartDataSet` add a different colour for each set.

```
    func updateGraph(){
        
        //create 2 ChartDataEntry arrays for both sets
        var dataEntries  : [ChartDataEntry] = []
        var dataEntries1  : [ChartDataEntry] = []
        
        
        //use ur condition here to devide the data in to two groups
        for i in 0..<numbers.count {
            if i < 3{
                let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: numbers[i]) // here we set the X and Y status in a data chart entry
                dataEntries.append(value)
            }else{
                let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: numbers[i]) // here we set the X and Y status in a data chart entry
                dataEntries1.append(value)
            }
        }
        
        //I add the last element of the first array to the begining of the first array to stop discontinue
        dataEntries1.insert(dataEntries.last!, at: 0)

        //create data set 1
        let set1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "Number")
        set1.colors = [UIColor.blue]

        //create data set 2
        let set2 = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries1, label: "Number")
        set2.colors = [UIColor.red]

        //This is the object that will be added to the chart
        let data = LineChartData(dataSets: [set1, set2])

        chtChart.data = data //finally - it adds the chart data to the chart and causes an update

    }
```

My Output looks like follows.

[image]

---

**Full ViewController Code**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtTextBox: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var chtChart: LineChartView!

    var numbers : [Double] = [] //This is where we are going to store all the numbers. This can be a set of numbers that come from a Realm database, Core data, External API's or where ever else

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var dataEntries  : [ChartDataEntry] = []
        numbers = [2,4,7,3,4,5,8,9,1,2,9]
        for i in 0..<numbers.count{
            let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: numbers[i]) // here we set the X and Y status in a data chart entry
            dataEntries.append(value)
        }
        let dataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "Number")
        dataSet.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = false
        dataSet.drawVerticalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true
        dataSet.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true
        dataSet.fillAlpha = 0.15
        dataSet.lineWidth = 2
        dataSet.circleRadius = 0
        dataSet.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false
        dataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
        dataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
        dataSet.highlightColor = .blue
        dataSet.colors = [UIColor.green]
        let data = LineChartData(dataSets: [dataSet])
        chtChart.data = data
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnbutton(_ sender: Any) {
//        let input  = Double(txtTextBox.text!) //gets input from the textbox - expects input as double/int
//        numbers.append(input!) //here we add the data to the array.
        updateGraph()
        txtTextBox.text = ""
    }

    func updateGraph(){
        
        //create 2 ChartDataEntry arrays for both sets
        var dataEntries  : [ChartDataEntry] = []
        var dataEntries1  : [ChartDataEntry] = []
        
        
        //use ur condition here to devide the data in to two groups
        for i in 0..<numbers.count {
            if i < 3{
                let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: numbers[i]) // here we set the X and Y status in a data chart entry
                dataEntries.append(value)
            }else{
                let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: numbers[i]) // here we set the X and Y status in a data chart entry
                dataEntries1.append(value)
            }
        }
        
        //I add the last element of the first array to the begining of the first array to stop discontinue
        dataEntries1.insert(dataEntries.last!, at: 0)
        
        //create data set 1
        let set1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "Number")
        set1.colors = [UIColor.blue]
        set1.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = false
        set1.drawVerticalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true
        set1.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true
        set1.fillAlpha = 0.15
        set1.lineWidth = 2
        set1.circleRadius = 0
        set1.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false
        set1.drawCirclesEnabled = false
        set1.drawValuesEnabled = false
        set1.highlightColor = .blue

        //create data set 2
        let set2 = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries1, label: "Number")
        set2.colors = [UIColor.red]
        set2.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = false
        set2.drawVerticalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true
        set2.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true
        set2.fillAlpha = 0.15
        set2.lineWidth = 2
        set2.circleRadius = 0
        set2.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false
        set2.drawCirclesEnabled = false
        set2.drawValuesEnabled = false
        set2.highlightColor = .blue
        //This is the object that will be added to the chart
        let data = LineChartData(dataSets: [set1, set2])
        
        chtChart.data = data //finally - it adds the chart data to the chart and causes an update
        
    }



}
```

Comment: Did you try it after a graph was already build?
I still get the same result...

Comment: Tried your way and still it look like my result...

Comment: yes it worked for me :(. I ll check again

Comment: wanna chat about it? :)